# How can i get the href for controllers in laravel using id

Tags: php, laravel-5, controller

I'm trying to create a hyperlink that redirects to user resource.

**This is my route**

```
Route::get('/user/{id}', 'UserController@show');
```

**This is my userController.php file**

```
public function show($id) {
    $users = User::find($id);
    return view('user.show', compact('users'));
}
```

**I'm  doing this**:

[image: not working]

**My blade file looks like this**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <h1>All Crads</h1>

    @foreach($users as $user)
        <p>
            <b><a href="{{ url('/user/{id}') }}">{{ $user->name }}:</a></b>
            <span>{{ $user->email }}</span>
        </p>

    @endforeach
@stop
```

Comment: Not related, but ... your users probably have unique ids, you can rename `$users` to `$user` and remove the `@foreach` in your blade.

Answer (score 0):

Use named routes. [Here's the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes).

By following those instructions your template will contain `route`. Something like this:

```
<a href="{{ route('foo', ['id' => 1]) }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is [named routing documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#named-routes) which explained how to use :

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <h1>All Crads</h1>

    @foreach($users as $user)
        <p>
            <b><a href="{{ route('route_name', array('id' => $user->id)) }}">{{ $user->name }}:</a></b>
            <span>{{ $user->email }}</span>
        </p>

    @endforeach
@stop
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
<a href="{{ url("/user/{$user->id}") }}">{{ $user->name }}</a>
```

please follow: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/urls#generating-basic-urls

You can also try:

```
<a href="{{ url("/user/".$user->id) }}">{{ $user->name }}</a>
```

Comment: Sorry, you need to use double quotes to parse variable.